# How to restrict a page [without plugin]

Tags: content-restriction, user-access

How to restricted a page in wordpress. For example : user [*without login*] can see 5 of game list. [example.com/game/]
and after click 'view more', **user must login/register** and after that, user **can access full/100 game list**. [example.com/game/]

Anyone know to make it without plugin? thank you

Comment: -1 – That’s pure plugin territory.

Comment: why you don't want to use plugin?

Comment: Found good resource to do that : https://www.scratchcode.io/how-to-restrict-pages-or-posts-access-without-login-into-wordpress

Answer (score 4):

You can do this pretty easily with a shortcode.  Hook into `init` and add the shortcode in your hooked function.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wpse57819_add_shortcode');
/**
 * Adds the shortcode
 *
 * @uses add_shortcode
 * @return null
 */
function wpse57819_add_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode('restricted', 'wpse57819_shortcode_cb');
}
```

Then in your callback function, you can check to see if the user is logged in.  If they are, show them the content.  If not, show them a login message. You can do literally whatever you want here: check for user capabilities to show them the content (different "membership levels"), show them an entire login form.  A simple example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Callback function for the shortcode.  Checks if a user is logged in.  If they
 * are, display the content.  If not, show them a link to the login form.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wpse57819_shortcode_cb($args, $content=null)
{
    // if the user is logged in just show them the content.  You could check
    // rolls and capabilities here if you wanted as well
    if(is_user_logged_in())
        return $content;

    // If we're here, they aren't logged in, show them a message
    $defaults = array(
        // message show to non-logged in users
        'msg'    => __('You must login to see this content.', 'wpse57819'),
        // Login page link
        'link'   => site_url('wp-login.php'),
        // login link anchor text
        'anchor' => __('Login.', 'wpse57819')
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

    $msg = sprintf(
        '<aside class="login-warning">%s <a href="%s">%s</a></aside>',
        esc_html($args['msg']),
        esc_url($args['link']),
        esc_html($args['anchor'])
    );

    return $msg;
}
```

As a [plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/restricted-content-shortcode.php).

**Usage**

Somewhere in your pages/posts:

```
[restricted]
Content for members only goes here
[/restricted]
```

Comment: You can drop the code above in your functions.php file (minus the opening `<?php` tags). Example usage added to the answer.

Comment: It's not in php code, the `[restricted]` is a shortcode: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: @Davis: Sorry, but not working in my syntax. 
[restricted]
<a href="sample.com">Sample</a>
[/restricted]
Whats wrong? thx

Comment: You're logged in.  That's probably what's wrong.

Comment: @Davis: Sorry, but coud this code put in any php file not in post. But in my case it didn't
<?
`php code`
[restricted]
`php code`
[/restricted]
`php code`
?>
Thank you

Comment: If you want to do it directly in a php file just use the `is_user_logged_in` conditional directly.

Comment: I have a page with shortcodes. it shows only shortcode names.. I did like this [restricted] [my-shortcode] [/restricted]. but it shows only "[my-shortcodes]" as a text. not real shortcode. so I have changed it to..."     return do_shortcode($content);" and it shows fine. am I doing right? what's different?

Answer (score 1):

May be a custom shortcode is useful
See this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrictedarea
It is obsolete but you should use the code for your pourpose

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add a custom meta box that allows you to mark the post as hidden.

> For detail please click on the [original answer this source link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250587/private-pages-that-work-when-you-are-not-logged-into-wp-admin)
>
> I modify this function to fulfill your needs

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'yourtextdomain_pre_get_posts_hidden', 9999 );
function yourtextdomain_pre_get_posts_hidden( $query )
{

  // Check if on frontend and main query.
    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) 
    {
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        {
            // For the posts we want to exclude.
            $exclude = array();

            // Locate our posts marked as hidden.
            $hidden = get_posts(array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                  'key' => 'meta-box-checkbox',
                  'value' => 'true',
                  'compare' => '==',
                ),
              )
            ));

               // Create an array of hidden posts.
            foreach($hidden as $hide)
            {
              $exclude[] = $hide->ID;
            }
            // Exclude the hidden posts.
            $query->set('post__not_in', $exclude);
        }

    }
}
```